# Delete Lines that contains string NULL

Tags: unix, notepad++

I'm trying to remove all lines that contains NULL, using Notepad++ as follows:

Line:

```
NULL,123456789333333
```

regular expersion I tried:

```
Find: ^.*NULL.*$
replace with:     (blank, nothing)
```

it deleted the line contents, but empty line still there. how to delete the whole line.

Comment: Notepad++ and Unix... what am I reading/seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: `^.*NULL.*\r\n` this won't delete the last line if there's NULL on it.